# Legal pages showing up in our Google Sitelinks

Tags: google, google-search-console, noindex, sitelinks

Our Terms of Service page (oursite.com/terms) is persistently showing up as the first of our Google Sitelinks, despite repeated demotions over the course of many weeks and the fact that we have plenty of other pages that are relevant and worthy of being Sitelinked.

It's driving us nuts, especially since one would assume Google's algorithms would be smart enough to identify boilerplate legal pages...

Anyway, we're thinking of noindexing the page. Anyone have a better idea, or think this is a bad one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine with noindexing the page, as there is no legal requirement to have T&C pages indexed (nor even included on a site).

However you might want to do a back link check and check traffic to the page in [GA](http://www.google.com.au/analytics/) first; perhaps people are linking to the page (unlikely) or it gets a lot of traffic and this could be why it keeps getting picked?

If this is the case (but i sense unlikely), you might want to actually leverage this, and use the page to drive traffic elsewhere on you site, in which case you wouldn't want to block it from Search engines.

But if not, then yeah just block it, either with robots meta tags, or in robots.txt.

Comment: Wow I think you might be on to something- Checked GA for past 2 weeks and while /terms is getting only small amount of traffic, it's still more than I expected and *twice* what the /about page gets... I'll have to decide what to do with that. Thanks-

Comment: Also, what _type_ of traffic are these pages getting? What search phrases are they using to find this page? Are people simply looking for examples of "T&Cs" (which they might want to "borrow" from), or are they specifically looking for _your_ T&Cs? The former is worth blocking, however, the later is valid traffic.